# fscanf outputting blob of text instead of an array

Tags: matlab, file-io, octave, scanf

So I've got a bunch of data that requires parsing. It's in the following format:

```
ATOM      1  N   VAL A   1       5.287  16.725   4.830  1.00 77.31           N   
ATOM      2  CA  VAL A   1       5.776  17.899   5.595  1.00 70.91           C  
ATOM      3  C   VAL A   1       7.198  18.266   5.104  1.00 81.71           C
```

etc.

The only things i need are the first 3 floating point numbers, obtainable using

```
A = fscanf(fid, '%*30c %f %f %f %*26c \n', [3, inf]);
```

which returns a nice 3 x n matrix containing these values.

The problem is that I only need the values for which the atom is "CA". I've tried a similar method for extracting this part like so:

```
B = fscanf(fid, '%*13c %s %*64c \n');
```

This works to the extent that I get the letters. The only problem is that I get them in a blob of text:

```
B = NCAC.... etc.
```

Instead of as a column vector or array.

Really I only need them to extract the float values I need, if there's a way to do this using fscanf then that's preferable, otherwise some way to have B not be a wall of text would be amazing.

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

OK, so with enough tinkering I found a way to do it.

I used `%3c` instead of `%s` to get the atom value, meaning the length of the output string would always be 3 times the number of atoms in the list. Then it's a simple loop to check if `B(i) = C`, `B(i + 1) = A` and `B(i + 2) = ' '`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the first few fields always being the same width, I'd use a more flexible approach such as:

```
fid = fopen('your_data.txt', 'r');

A = textscan(fid, '%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s %f %f %f %*f%*f%*s',...
        'MultipleDelimsAsOne', true);

fclose(fid);
```

This only relies on the *number* of fields, not their *width*. Then, to get only the fields labelled `CA`, use

```
fid = fopen('your_data.txt', 'r');

A = textscan(fid, '%*s%*s %s %*s%*s%*s %f %f %f %*f%*f%*s',...
        'MultipleDelimsAsOne', true);

fclose(fid);

A = cellfun(@(x) x( strcmp(A{1}, 'CA') ), A(2:end))
```